# How to duplicate MySQL Datatabase + include Stored Procedure (Routines)

Tags: mysql

if I want copy/backup database to the same server, I try:

```
mysqldump -u root -pfirdi --opt fdev | mysql -u root -pfirdi fdev2
```

but NOT include the Stored Procedure.

if I try to run:

```
mysqldump -u root -pfirdi -R --opt fdev | mysql -u root -pfirdi fdev2
```

(I add option '-R' in the line), it still can not (hang).

Does anyone can help me?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use something like this:

```
mysqldump ... -v -R yourDatabase | mysql ...
```

If your database is too large, you may need to dump it to a file first, and then load it into your server:

```
mysqldump ... > sqlFile.sql
mysql ... < sqlFile.sql
```

In Linux, something like this may work:

```
mysqldump ... > sqlFile.sql && mysql ... < sqlFile.sql && rm sqlFile.sql
```

This will:

1. Dump the database to `sqlFile.sql`
2. Load `sqlFile.sql` to your new database (only if the dump was successful)
3. Delete `sqlFile.sql` (only if the load operation was successful).

If any of these steps fails, the instruction will stop.

**Some useful options for `mysqldump`**:

- `--delayed-insert`: Usues [`insert delayed`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) instead of normal insert.
- `--disable-keys`: Encloses the insert instructions for each table between `alter table ... disable keys` and `alter table ... enable keys`. That may improve the insert speed
- `-v`: Output what `mysqldump` is doing to Standard output. This is useful if you want to find out what table is hanging your dump.
- `-R`: Also export stored procedures and functions.
- `-d`: Only dump data structures... it is useful if you want to create a database "template". Using `-R` and `-d` together creates an empty database dump (no data), with routines.

If you are having problems exporting the routines, you can try something like this:

1. Create a "no data" dump of your database: `mysql ... -d -R` > emptyDbDump.sql`
2. Edit the `emptyDbDump.sql` file with a text editor to remove all table and view definitions (leave only the stored functions and procedures definitions).
3. Load this new `emptyDbDump.sql` file to your new database.

Take a look to the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) for additional information.

Hope this helps

Comment: ic... I just try (on OS Windows):
1. mysqldump -u root -pfirdi -v -R fdev > fdev.sql
2. mysql -u root -pfirdi fdev2 < fdev.sql

and it works... :D thank you mr. Barranka. 

I thought it can just single line like "mysqldump -u root -pfirdi -R --opt fdev | mysql -u root -pfirdi fdev2", but it can not...

Comment: @Firdi Sometimes, if the database is too big, MySQL can't process all the inserts at the same speed as MySQLdump is sending them... so it is sometimes a good idea to dump the database to a file first and then load it to your server.